# Jetpack Compose: Mimicking spinner.setSelection() inside of a DropDownMenu

Tags: android, drop-down-menu, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack, composable

The use case is that you have 10s or 100s of items inside of a dropdown menu, the dropdown options have some ordering - as with number values or alphabetical listing of words  - and selections are made in succession.

When the user reopens the menu, you'd like for it to open in the same region as their last selection, so that for instance you don't jump from "car" to "apple" but rather from "car" to "cat". Or if they just opted to view order number 358, they can quickly view order number 359.

Using views, you could create a `Spinner` and put all of your items in an `ArrayAdapter` and then call `spinner.setSelection()` to scroll directly to the index you want.

`DropdownMenu` doesn't have anything like `HorizontalPager`'s `scrollToPage()`. So what solutions might exist to achieve this?

So far, I've tried adding `verticalScroll()` to the `DropdownMenu`'s modifier and trying to do arithmetic with the scrollState. But it crashes at runtime with an error saying the component has infinite height, the same error you get if you try to nest scrollable components like a `LazyColumn` inside of a `Column` with verticalScroll.

Answer (score 2):

It's a [known issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/185304441).

`DropdownMenu` [has its own](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/185304441) vertical scroll modifier inside, and there is no API to work with it.

Until this problem is fixed by providing a suitable API, the only workaround I can think of is to create your own view - you can take the source code of `DropdownMenu` as reference.

Comment: Wow that really wasn't complicated at all.  ```DropdownMenu``` calls ```DropdownMenuContent```, and that's where they set ```.verticalScroll(rememberScrollState())```. I just changed ```rememberScrollState``` to ```parentProvidedScrollState``` and then move pass ```parentProvidedScrollState``` down from my view down to DropdownMenu and down to DropdownMenu content. Then I call scrollTo() inside the same onClick() that opens the menu. I really want to know though, is there an easier way to modify Android library code rather than cutting and pasting and renaming them? What's the right way?

Comment: @D.Kupra no, there's no other way. Only letting the maintainers know via the issue tracker that you'd like to see a new feature, but it's already done.

Answer (score 1):

I'll post a more detailed answer here because I don't want to mislead anyone with my comment above.

If you're in Android Studio, click the three dots on the mouse-hover quick documentation box and select "edit source" to open the source for `DropdownMenu` in AndroidMenu.android.kt. Then observe that it uses a composable called `DropdownMenuItemContent`. Edit source again and you're in Menu.kt.

You'll see this:

```
@Composable
internal fun DropdownMenuContent(
...
...
...
{
        Column(
            modifier = modifier
                .padding(vertical = DropdownMenuVerticalPadding)
                .width(IntrinsicSize.Max)
                .verticalScroll(rememberScrollState()),//<-We want this
            content = content
        )
    }
```

So in your custom composable just replace that `rememberScrollState()` with your favorite variable name for a ScrollState.

And then chain that reference all the way back up to your original view.

**Getting Access to the ScrollState**

```
@Composable 
fun MyCustomDropdownMenu(
    expanded:Boolean,
    scrollStateProvidedByTopParent:ScrollState,
    ...
    ...
   )
   {...}

@Composable
fun MyCustomDropdownMenuContent(
    scrollStateProvidedByTopParent:ScrollState,
    ...
    ...
    )
    {...}


//And now for your actual content

@Composable
fun TopParent(){
    val scrollStateProvidedByTopParent=rememberScrollState()
    val spinnerExpanded by remember{mutableStateOf(false)}
    ...
    ...
    Box{
       Row(modifier=Modifier.clickable(onClick={spinnerExpanded=!spinnerExpanded}))//<-More about this line in the sequel
    {
      Text("Options")
      Icon(imageVector = Icons.Filled.ArrowDropDown, contentDescription = "")
      
      MyCustomDropdownMenu(
      expanded = spinnerExpanded,
      scrollStateProvidedByTopParent=scrollStateProvidedByTopParent,
      onDismissRequest = { spinnerExpanded = false }) 
    {//your spinner content}

       }
    }
}
```

The above only specifies how to access the `ScrollState` of the `DropdownMenu`. But once you have the `ScrollState`, you'll have to do some arithmetic to get the scroll position right when it opens. Here's one way that seems alright.

**Calculating the scroll distance**

Even after setting the contents of the menu items explicitly, the distance was never quite right if I relied on those values. So I used an `onTextLayout` callback inside the `Text` of my menu items in order to get the true `Text` height at the time of rendering. Then I use that value for the arithmetic. It looks like this:

```
@Composable
fun TopParent(){
    val scrollStateProvidedByTopParent=rememberScrollState()
    val spinnerExpanded by remember{mutableStateOf(false)}
    val chosenText:String by remember{mutableStateOf(myListOfSpinnerOptions[0])
    val height by remember{mutableStateOf(0)}
    val heightHasBeenChecked by remember{mutableStateOf(false)}
    val coroutineScope=rememberCoroutineScope()

    ...
    ...
    Box{
       Row(modifier=Modifier.clickable(onClick={spinnerExpanded=!spinnerExpanded
 coroutineScope.launch{scrollStateProvidedByTopParent.scrollTo(height*myListOfSpinnerOptions.indexOf[chosenText])}}))//<-This gets some arithmetic for scrolling distance
    {
      Text("Options")
      Icon(imageVector = Icons.Filled.ArrowDropDown, contentDescription = "")
          
      MyCustomDropdownMenu(
      expanded = spinnerExpanded,
      scrollStateProvidedByTopParent=scrollStateProvidedByTopParent,
      onDismissRequest = { spinnerExpanded = false }) {
        myListOfSpinnerOptions.forEach{option->  
        DropdownMenuItem(onClick={
            chosenText=option    
            spinnerExpanded=false
            }){
              Text(option,onTextLayout={layoutResult->
              if (!heightHasBeenChecked){
                 height=layoutResults.size.height
                 heightHasBeenChecked=true
                 }
              }
              )

              }
          }
      }  
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the Material 3 version 1.2.0-alpha02, scrollState parameter was added to the DropdownMenu().

Referring  to  [this sample from android.com](https://cs.android.com/androidx/platform/frameworks/support/+/androidx-main:compose/material3/material3/samples/src/main/java/androidx/compose/material3/samples/MenuSamples.kt)

They have an example of using a scroll state for DropDownMenu.
To emulate the  "setSelection" in a spinner, you call scrollState.scrollTo(xxx)

Refer to the part in LaunchedEffect

```
@Composable
fun MyUI() {
    var expanded by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
    val contextForToast = LocalContext.current.applicationContext
    val scrollState = rememberScrollState()

    Box(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .wrapContentSize(Alignment.Center),
        contentAlignment = Alignment.Center
    ) {
        // vertical 3 dots button
        IconButton(
            onClick = {
                expanded = true
            }
        ) {
            Icon(Icons.Default.MoreVert, contentDescription = "Open Menu")
        }

        DropdownMenu(
            expanded = expanded,
            onDismissRequest = { expanded = false },
            scrollState = scrollState
        ) {
            repeat(30) {
                DropdownMenuItem(
                    text = {
                        Text("Item $it")
                    },
                    onClick = {
                        Toast.makeText(contextForToast, "Item $it", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()       
                        expanded = false
                    }
                )
            }
        }
    }

    LaunchedEffect(expanded) {
        if (expanded) {
            // scroll to the last item
            scrollState.scrollTo(scrollState.maxValue)
        }
    }
}
```